# Ruby #times not returning what I think it should

Tags: ruby

I was expecting to get:

```
array # => [[1, 0], [2, 0]]
```

If I run the following code:

```
array = []
position = [0, 0]
2.times do
  position[0] += 1
  array << position
end
```

I get:

```
array # => [[2, 0], [2, 0]]
```

Can someone please explain what is happening here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`position` is an object.  When you call `array << position`, what you're really doing is adding the reference to `position` to `array`.  This means that anytime you modify `position`, all references to it will reflect those changes.

To get the result that you're expecting, you can make a copy of the `position` array on each pass.  That way, subsequent passes won't alter your results.

```
array = []
position = [0, 0]

2.times do
  position[0] += 1
  array << position.clone
end

puts array.inspect
```

Comment: Alternatively, `2.times do; array << [ position[0] += 1, *position[1..-1]]; end;
array #=> [[1, 0], [2, 0]]`.

Comment: If I set position to 0 and then increment position. The final array.inspect would show [1, 2]. Why isn't this then [2, 2]?

Comment: @JosephTimmer Numbers and other "primitive" types in ruby are immutable.  This means that you cannot alter the state of that memory.  When you increment position, you're actually creating an all new number and reassigning it to position.  Thus, the numbers originally placed into ```array``` remain the same.

Tonys answer has a good explanation of how mutable objects work.

Answer (score 1):

The thing here is that position[0] is first equal to [0,1] with your statement:

```
position[0] += 1
```

This makes it seem like you're 'shoveling' [0,1] in the first time and [0,2] the second time. The thing with the shovel operator is that it isn't like the `=` assignment. This has to do with the concept that the `<<` 'mutates the caller'. I find it's easier to understand this by seeing it in action:

```
a = "Hello!"
b = a
a << ", my friend"
puts a      # a is now "Hello!, my friend"
puts b      # b is now "Hello!, my friend"
```

The `<<` operator doesn't reassign what `a` is pointing to in memory space. Contrast this to the `=` operator, which doesn't mutate the caller:

```
a = "How about this?"
b = a    # b is now "How about this?"
a = "Not anymore"
puts b   # b is still "How about this?"
puts a   # a is now "Now anymore"
```

The other good answer regarding using the `.clone` method is important because it does what's called a "shallow copy", which means the instance variables of the object are copied, but not the objects they reference. That's why it works for this situation.

Hopefully seeing how the shovel operator works, and that changing the value with it is altering *all* of it's references and not just one and makes the output all the same in the array. If this doesn't make complete sense, let me know in the comments.